# firebase reference downloadURL function not work

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, swift5

I use firebase and I would like to get images. but I can't. I don't understand why? When I set breakpoint, it does not enter these lines.not work means that not enter. How can I solve this problem ?

[image]
breakpoints not enter these lines >> 222-230

[image]
breakpoints enter line 429. but breakpoint  not enter line 431-437

```
 for index in 0..<20 {
       let item = imagesRef[index]
       self.downloadURLStorage(for: item) { res in
           switch res {
           case .success(let myUrl):
               //print(myUrl)

           case .failure(let error):
               print(error.localizedDescription)
               
           }
       }
       
      
   }
```

example item  gs://m-2023.appspot.com/images/000000000000001 - Three buttons.png

```
func downloadURLStorage(for reference: StorageReference, completion: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void) {
            
        reference.downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
            guard let url = url, error == nil else {
                        
                completion(.failure(error!))
                        return
            }
            completion(.success(url))
        })
    }
```

Comment: "not work" is really hard to help with. When you step through this code line by line in a debugger, and inspect every variable on every line - what is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I did debug to code line by line and you can see I wrote line 429 is working. but 431-437 not work

Comment: Again: "not work" is really hard to help with. What happens on those lines? Is there an error message? Can you maybe `print` something that show the problem?

Comment: sorry . When I set breakpoint, it does not enter these lines.

Comment: More troubleshooting is needed as the issue could be a number of things. For example, the call to `func downloadURLStorage(for reference: StorageReference` is this `self.downloadURLStorage(for: item)` but we don't know what item resolved to. That data that needs to be in the question so we don't have to guess. Likewise is `func downloadURLStorage(for` even actually being called? Add a print statement as the first line within the function `print(#function)` and see if the function name prints to console. I would also change the error handling to identify either url error or an actual error.